# If $x(b-c)+y(c-a)+z(a-b)=0$ then show that ..

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck with the following problem that says:

> If $x(b-c)+y(c-a)+z(a-b)=0$ then show that 
>   $$\frac{bz-cy}{b-c}=\frac{cx-az}{c-a}=\frac{ay-bx}{a-b}$$ where $a \neq b \neq c.$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time .

Comment: Please post the *complete* question. As it is now, it's false - take for example $a=b=c\,$.

Comment: This is the complete question..May be the question itself is wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$-(a-b)z=x(b-c)+y(c-a)$$

$$\frac{bz-cy}{b-c}=\dfrac{-b\{x(b-c)+y(c-a)\}-c(a-b)y}{(b-c)(a-b)}=?$$

Comment: got it..Thanks a lot for the clarification...

Comment: @learner, Welcome! Please follow: https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall and https://archive.org/details/higheralgebra032813mbp

Comment: thanks for sharing the link.